# Spring Source Toolsuite (STS) - Batch-Graph when using Java-Config

Tags: java, spring, visualization, spring-batch, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

this is my first Batch-Project where I want to avoid writing XML-Files and use for configurations Java-Config. So I have few Batch-Jobs and application works as expected.

For documentation reasons or presentation I would like to use the possibility of Spring-IDE to show batch-graph what works very good when using spring-config in XML.

But I am not available to find how I can use Batch-Graph when Batch-Job is configured in Java.

I already scanned all spring-configuation within Eclipse, so in the Spring-View I can see my Java-Config-Class, but I don't know how to bring it into Batch-Graph.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think this feature isn't implemented in STS yet. Please file an enhancement request for this here: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS

Comment: It seems you are right, and I did request at jira. https://issuetracker.springsource.com/i#browse/STS-3934

Comment: The successor to STS-3934 on github is https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/209