# Jobs Schema Designer - Spring Batch

Tags: eclipse, spring-batch, spring-tool-suite

Does it exist a tool to generate a Jobs schema from a Spring Batch project ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for something like the batch graph feature of STS: https://dzone.com/refcardz/eclipse-tools-spring?chapter=8 ? It works with XML though, it looks like Java config is not supported yet, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314672/spring-source-toolsuite-sts-batch-graph-when-using-java-config and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/209

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I use STS, and @Configuration style ( spring boot annotation), and not a XML config files

Comment: The Spring Tools 4 do not provide a feature to render a graph for a Spring Batch definition yet, but feel free to file an enhancement request here: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues - including samples and a description of what exactly you would like to use. Generating a graphical representation for a Spring Batch definition defined using annotations might be a quite complicated challenge though.